# Dimension is not filling aggregates

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I am having trouble with setting dimension

```
My DB:

PERSON:
id PRIMARY KEY
name

SALES:
id
person_id FOREIGN KEY -> person.id
value
```

Now i want to make a CUBE SALES with DIMENSION PERSON and MEASURE VALUE

```
CUBE
-table: SALES
-dimension: PERSON (foreign key: person_id)
   -hierarchy: default
      -level: name
      **-level: id** (originaly not here, see below)
      -table: Person
-Measure: value (sum)
```

now i want to do this:

```
select [MEASURE].[VALUE] on columns,
   {[PERSON].[NAME].members} on rows
from SALES
```

it doesnt fill sum of values unless i put BOLD line
I don't know where am I making mistake, i think that something with my DB setup is not right, but i tried everything.

EDIT:
I looked up in a xml and changed things that pentaho mondrian shema-workbench made:
i deleted types and one thing is necessary and it is a primary key attribute in hierarchy.
Now it is working